# Glassfish Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, glassfish

What is Glassfish and Tomcat for? I have searched them and it says GlassFish is an open-source application server project started by Sun Microsystems for the Java EE platform but I don't really understand. Can anyone explain to me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How would you compare Apache Tomcat & Glassfish as production servers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327793/how-would-you-compare-apache-tomcat-glassfish-as-production-servers)

Answer (score 6):

Both are server environments for running J2EE (Java Enterprise) applications. Glassfish is a full blown server implementation while Tomcat is a container implementation:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition

http://wiki.glassfish.java.net/Wiki.jsp?page=FaqGlassFishTomcat