# GlassFish vs tomcat

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, application-server, tomcat5.5

I would like to start using JEE6 in the next project that I have to work on at my job, but there is also a limitation (sort of): Tomcat 5.5
My question is, what improvements would bring GlassFish to the table (security/speed) vs the existing Tomcat(5.5) or an upgrade to the newer version 7?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is difference between Tomcat and JBoss and Glassfish?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821640/what-is-difference-between-tomcat-and-jboss-and-glassfish), http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327793/how-would-you-compare-apache-tomcat-glassfish-as-production-servers

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> **Q:** My question is, what improvements would bring GlassFish to the table
>   (security/speed) vs the existing Tomcat(5.5) or an upgrade to the
>   newer version 7?

Tomcat 7 compared to Tomcat 5.5 supports newer version of JSR specifications. Therefore, if you wish to use for example Servlet 3.0 or Websockets, you don't have other choice but to upgrade the Tomcat version. See [this link](http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html) for the full list of Tomcat versions and supported specifications.

However, Tomcat is not Java EE container, but only a servlet container. In other words, if you plan to use full Java EE (which includes security and many other things), you have to switch from Tomcat to some of full Java EE application servers. Glassfish is one of them, others are TomEE (similar to Tomcat, so perhaps a good starting point), WildFly, IBM Websphere, Oracle Weblogic etc. Unfortunately, Oracle recently decided to abandon commercial support for Glassfish, so maybe it would be wise choice to go with some other application server if you would like to use it commercially.

One way or another, move from Tomcat 5.5 because it is a quite old version of Tomcat.

See also:

- [Java EE containers vs Web containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17181292/java-ee-containers-vs-web-containers/17184620)
- [Oracle abandons commercial support for Glassfish JEE Server](http://www.zdnet.com/oracle-abandons-commercial-support-for-glassfish-jee-server-7000022945/)